# unwanted notification from email address

Tags: iphone

I keep getting notification of missed facetime from an email address, they come 2 notfications at the time.  I've tried blocking the caller, but it's not a caller it's an email.  how can I stop this

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [How to Block an Email Address on iPhone](http://www.wikihow.com/Block-an-Email-Address-on-iPhone) as the information might be helpful.

Comment: It is not in Mail. The OP specifically stated they are Facetime notifications. Also, please don't use `code` tags for things that are not code. iPhone and Mail are normal words. If you want to emphasize something, use **bold** or _italics_.

Comment: That said, adding the email address of the caller to the contact you blocked should cause it to block attempted Facetime calls as well.

Comment: Whoever down-voted this care to explain why, did you actually test the steps and it didn't work?

Comment: Not sure who downvoted it, but link-only answers are generally frowned-upon, as the information in the link can change or disappear, making the answer useless at that point. I'd suggest editing in the relevant information from the link (summarize the steps involved) and explain how it pertains to the user's situation, as it might not be immediately clear.